# connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed when i want to connect to django database container from celery task

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, celery

I'm working on a django application with docker. I have a celery container which uses another redis container as brocker and backend. My postgres database is also in another container. Everything works well. But when I try to perform database operations in tasks, celery returns me: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed

here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: ozangue
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db && 
      python manage.py makemigrations &&
      python manage.py migrate && 
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./electron:/electron
      - ./data/web:/vol/web
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=devsecretkey
      - DEBUG=1
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=xxxxx
      - DB_USER=xxxxxx
      - DB_PASS=xxxxxx
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  celery:
    container_name: celery-worker
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./celery
    command: celery -A electron worker -l info -E
    depends_on:
      - app
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.5-alpine
    container_name: redis
    expose:
      - 6379
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    container_name: database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
```

celery.py

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","electron.settings")

app = Celery('electron', broker='redis://redis:6379/0',backend='redis://redis:6379/0')

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings",namespace="CELERY")

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

settings

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER","redis://redis:6379/0")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER","redis://redis:6379/0")
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

How to solve this problem please?

Comment: It seems like you set some database-related environment variables like `DB_HOST=db` for the `app` container, but not the `celery` container.  Do you need to duplicate its `environment:` block?

Comment: Do you mean I have to add this block for celery in docker-compose?

Comment: Is that the entirely of the message?  There should be more to it, saying why it failed.

Comment: @DavidMaze it worked. Thank you !